# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x f'(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $ (0, \infty) $. Knowing that 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x f(x) = 0 ,\;\;\;\; \lim_{x\to\infty} x f''(x) = 0.$$
Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x f'(x) = 0$.

Current idea to finish this problem is to use Taylor's theorem and function $f(x+1)$ but my hour long attempts to do that have faced failure. 
So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A suggestion: maybe $g(x)=f({1\over x})$ helps. Then try to analyze $g(x)$ around $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Let $x > 0$. Taylor's theorem gives you $$f(x+1) - f(x) = f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} f''(\xi)$$ where $\xi \in (x,x+1)$. Rearrange to get
$$|f'(x)| \le |f(x+1)| + |f(x)| + \frac 12 |f''(\xi)|$$
which in turn leads to
$$x |f'(x)| \le (x+1)|f(x+1)| + x|f(x)| + \frac{\xi}{2} |f''(\xi)|.$$
By hypothesis, given an $\epsilon > 0$ you can find $M > 0$ with the property that if $x > M$ then all three terms on the right are less than $\epsilon/3$.

Comment: By the same way: More generally, if $g(x)$ is eventually positive and non-decreasing, then $g(x)f(x)\to 0 $ and $g(x)f''(x)\to 0$ imply $g(x)f'(x)\to 0$.

Comment: I must say that I am a bit lost on finding that M there... Do I understand it correctly that finding M is similiar to epsilon delta proofs with limits?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by reviewing exactly what $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x) = 0$ means.